# Wait for python script to execute in node js

Tags: python, node.js, image, image-processing

I am trying to take an image as input from the user and process it using python and then display the processed result in node js. For this, user first uploads an image, then I save it in uploads folder. Then, python script takes that image and processes it and saved it in the same location. Finally, I display the new image.
I have tried using async statements and promise, but they don't seem to work.

```
app.post("/image", function(req, res){
  upload(req, res, (err)=> {  
    if(err){
      res.render('upload', {
      msg: err
      });
    } else {
      const promise = call_python(req, res);
      res.render('upload', {
        file: `./uploads/detected.png`
      });
    }
  })
})
```

call_python calls the python script using spawn.

upload just uses multer to save the image.

My image tag looks like- `<img src="<%= typeof file != 'undefined' ? file : '' %>" class="responsive-img">`

EDIT: I have now included call_python as below.

```
async function call_python (req, res) {
  var spawn = require("child-process-promise").spawn;
  let promise = await new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
    try {
    spawn('python', ["script.py"], {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr', 'on']})
    resolve(1)
    }
    catch (err) { console.log(err)}
}).catch(()=> {})
return promise;
```

Comment: do you really need python?Honestly i dont like this approach, i think is better to do some kind of pooling. Es. save image and image image path in db -> every n time python check if there are new images to process  if so process it and so on.

Comment: I am just doing it as a side project to learn node. Thanks, I will take your advice into consideration next time.

Comment: is the image actually uploaded? what you get as output?

Comment: I save it in public/uploads after user submits the image. My output is just the processed image being displayed (after saving the image using python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the  call_python() functions async all you have to do is:

```
app.post("/image", function(req, res){
  upload(req, res, async (err)=> {  
    if(err){
      res.render('upload', {
      msg: err
      });
    } else {
      await call_python(req, res);
      res.render('upload', {
        file: `./uploads/detected.png`
      });
    }
  })
})
```

you have to "wait" for it to be done before you execute next command.

and for the call_functiom:

```
async function call_python (req, res) {
  const spawnSync = require("child-process-promise").spawnSync;
  return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
    try {
    spawnSync('python', ["script.py"], {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr', 'on']})
    resolve(1)
    }
    catch (err) { console.log(err)}
  }).catch(()=> {})
}
```

your gonna need to understand that the spwan() is async, make it sync to return the resolve after it ends.

Comment: what do you mean by wait? Is it some command you are talking about or to actually wait till python script is completed executing?

Comment: You said your using call_python asynchronous, if its type of Promise, you can just put await, if it receive a callback your gonna have to do everything inside the callback

Comment: I have added the call_python above. After doing the changes you mentioned, I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: Take a look now,@sudddddd
you need sync spawn

Comment: I am getting error- ReferenceError: spawnSync is not defined

Comment: @sudddddd ye, look now

Comment: changing to `const spawnSync = require("child_process").spawnSync;` works. But the problem now is that the processed image is not displaying.